# ensureCapacity(int minimumCapacity) method in StringBuffer class

Tags: java, stringbuffer

As per the oracle docs, refer to this link [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#capacity%28%29)

```
public void ensureCapacity(int minimumCapacity)

Ensures that the capacity is at least equal to the specified minimum. 
If the current capacity is less than the argument, then a new internal array 
is allocated with greater capacity. 

The new capacity is the larger of:
The minimumCapacity argument.
Twice the old capacity, plus 2.
If the minimumCapacity argument is nonpositive, this method takes no action and simply returns.
```

I am trying to clear it with a code sample:

```
    StringBuffer buff1 = new StringBuffer("tuts point");
    System.out.println("buffer1 = " + buff1);        // lenght = 10

    // returns the current capacity of the string buffer 1
    System.out.println("Old Capacity = " + buff1.capacity());  // capacity = 16+10=26 characters
    /*
     * increases the capacity, as needed, to the specified amount in the
     * given string buffer object
     */
    // returns twice the capacity plus 2
    buff1.ensureCapacity(30);
    System.out.println("New Capacity = " + buff1.capacity()); // 26*2 + 2 = 54
```

If the minimumCapacity argument in the ensureCapacity methods is in between 27 - 53, then i do get the expected answer(returns twice the capacity plus 2).
However, if the argument is>=55, the capacity is equal to this argument only.

```
    // does not return (twice the capacity plus 2)
    buff1.ensureCapacity(55);
    System.out.println("New Capacity = " + buff1.capacity());  // 55
```

Why 55 is the answer here?

Comment: Check your arithmetic. 26*2 + 2 = 54 not 56. Numbers from 27-53 are smaller than 54. 55 is larger than 54.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 : ok boss. Edited!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to this call on the `AbstractStringBuilder` class:

```
void expandCapacity(int minimumCapacity) {
    int newCapacity = value.length * 2 + 2;
    if (newCapacity - minimumCapacity < 0)
        newCapacity = minimumCapacity;
    if (newCapacity < 0) {
        if (minimumCapacity < 0) // overflow
            throw new OutOfMemoryError();
        newCapacity = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    value = Arrays.copyOf(value, newCapacity);
}
```

So, when it increases the capacity, it will increase the capacity by a minimum of (2 * original caparicty) + 2, to the value provided, whichever one is larger.

if the capacity is 26, and you pass 30:

(26 * 2) + 2 = 54, this is more than 30, so the new capacity will be 54.

if the capacity is 26, and you pass 55:

(26 * 2) + 2 = 54, this is less than 55, so the new capacity will be 55.

Comment: Check your last line : (26 * 2) + 2 = 54, this is less than 30, (should be greater than)

Answer (score 1):

I am sure the answer is going to be implementation detail of the vm, but

for example

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/StringBuffer.java#StringBuffer.ensureCapacity%28int%29

```
public synchronized void More ...ensureCapacity(int minimumCapacity) {
       if (minimumCapacity > value.length) {
            expandCapacity(minimumCapacity);
        }
    }
```

which calls expandCapacity in `AbstractStringBuilder`

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java#AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity%28int%29

```
void expandCapacity(int minimumCapacity) {
         int newCapacity = (value.length + 1) * 2;
         if (newCapacity < 0) {
             newCapacity = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
         } else if (minimumCapacity > newCapacity) {
             newCapacity = minimumCapacity;
         }
         value = Arrays.copyOf(value, newCapacity);
     }
```

but I don't see it returning 55.   So more code exploring. is needed (Also this the openjdk source. not sure what has changed or is different to your vm